# Is this esp8266 antenna layout any good?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, wireless, esp8266, wifi

[image]

It's the first time I do a design based on ESP8266 ic (not module) and was wondering if this layout is permissible for 2.4Ghz applications. I acknowledge that the trace must be a bit wider to comply with the 50Ohm impedance required to transmit/receive at max power (i used an online microstrip calculator and the trace should be much wider than the design).

Just any advice or suggestion about the vias or the way I placed the lna components is all I need.
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add some vias down the right hand side where the C7 legend is. You need to fence in them RFs so they don’t escape! I’d be looking at the Espressif layout examples to see how they handle it - especially under the chip.